# C# generic utility to check JSON string for anonymous type

Tags: c#, json, generics, anonymous-objects

I have a JSON string. I want to check if it contains an anonymous object. If it does then return the value. If it doesn't then return a default value. I then want to be able to repeat this multiple times for different anonymous objects.

Here is a sample of the code that I have currently implemented but obviously it is duplicated each time and not very "clean".

```
var displayDataBy = 0;
var displayDataByDefinition = new { DisplayDataBy = new { Key = "string", Value = displayDataBy } };
var displayDataByResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(this.OhdContentPageParameters, displayDataByDefinition);
try { displayDataBy = displayDataByResult.DisplayDataBy.Value; }
catch { }

var xMinsOeeToShow = 480;
var xMinsOeeToShowDefinition = new { XMinsOeeToShow = new { Key = "string", Value = xMinsOeeToShow } };
var xMinsOeeToShowResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(this.OhdContentPageParameters, xMinsOeeToShowDefinition);
try { xMinsOeeToShow = xMinsOeeToShowResult.XMinsOeeToShow.Value; }
catch { }
```

I would prefer it was a generic method that I could call for each anonymous type. Also it would be nice to not have to rely on the try/catch. Can it be done?

**UPDATE...**

This is working great for int, bool and double:

```
public static T2 DeserializeValue<T, T2>(this string json, T definition, T2 defaultValue, Func<T, T2?> getValueFunc) where T2 : struct
{
    var jsonAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);
    return getValueFunc(jsonAnon) ?? defaultValue;
}
```

I added this for strings:

```
public static string DeserializeStringValue<T>(this string json, T definition, string defaultValue, Func<T, string> getValueFunc)
{
    var jsonAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);
    return getValueFunc(jsonAnon) ?? defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a helper class to generalize the operations you are performing,

```
public static class DeserializeHelpers {
    public static T2 DeserializeValue<T,T2>(this string s, T def, T2 defans, Func<T, T2?> getAnsFn) where T2 : struct {
        var jsonAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(s, def);
        return getAnsFn(jsonAnon) ?? defans;
    }

    public static T2 DeserializeClass<T,T2>(this string s, T def, T2 defans, Func<T, T2> getAnsFn) where T2 : class {
        var jsonAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(s, def);
        return getAnsFn(jsonAnon) ?? defans;
    }
}
```

You can slightly simplify your code as follows. I left in some of the verbose coding as you seemed to be going to great lengths to avoid putting in an explicit type for `Value` but I was forced to assume it was a value type to allow for `null` returns from the member accessor lambda. If a class might be returned, you would need to use the class helper.

```
var displayDataBy = 0;
var displayDataByDefinition = new { DisplayDataBy = new { Key = "string", Value = displayDataBy } };
var displayDataByResult = this.OhdContentPageParameters.DeserializeValue(displayDataByDefinition, displayDataBy, x => x.DisplayDataBy?.Value);

var xMinsOeeToShow = 480;
var xMinsOeeToShowDefinition = new { XMinsOeeToShow = new { Key = "string", Value = xMinsOeeToShow } };
var xMinsOeeToShowResult = this.OhdContentPageParameters.DeserializeValue(xMinsOeeToShowDefinition, xMinsOeeToShow, x => x.XMinsOeeToShow?.Value);
```

I used an extension method for `Deserialize...` but of course it could be a regular method.

If you don't need to reuse the anonymous type definition you could pass that inline to the `Deserialize...` method.

Comment: It wasn't intentional to avoid putting an explicit type for `Value`. The type of `Value` is known. Feel free to update your answer. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: Your solution worked great for int, double and bool. I had to create a 2nd very similar method for strings. I updated the original post with the solution.

Comment: @StephenRichardson The `DeserializeClass` method should work for String as well, though I agree its naming is a bit suspect in that case. Maybe `DeserializeReference`?

Comment: Ah ok. I didn’t realise that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try with conditional operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

```
var displayDataBy = 0;
…..
displayDataBy = (displayDataByResult?.DisplayDataBy?.Value == null ? displayDataBy : displayDataByResult.DisplayDataBy.Value);


var xMinsOeeToShow = 480;
…...
xMinsOeeToShow = (xMinsOeeToShowResult?.XMinsOeeToShow?.Value == null ? xMinsOeeToShow : xMinsOeeToShowResult.XMinsOeeToShow.Value);
```

Comment: This can be further simplified when combining with the [Null-Coalescing (??) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). E.g.: `displayDataBy = (displayDataByResult?.DisplayDataBy?.Value ?? displayDataBy);`

Comment: Thanks, this removes the try catch. Please see my update adding clarity regarding the generic method.

Comment: @dbc I asked one question. This answer offered here did not answer my question. I updated my original post with extra clarity to help guide answers better...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
public object GetStuffDone(int displayDataBy, string KeyName, string Ohd, int defaultValue)
        {
            var definition = new { theData = new { Key = KeyName, Value = displayDataBy } };

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(Ohd, definition);


            return result != null ? result.theData.Value : defaultValue;
        }
```

Comment: `theData` is the thing that needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JObject.Parse instead of deserialize?

```
Func<Type, string, object, string, object> getValue = (T, path, dflt, json) =>
            {
                var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
                return jobj.SelectToken(path).ToObject(T) ?? dflt;
            };

var result = (int)getValue(typeof(int), "*.Value", 0, this.OhdContentPageParameters);
```

With this, you can traverse your Json through a JsonPath and set a default. No need to declare anonymous types.

Is there a need to explicitly know the property of JSON you are retrieving from?